# jQuery simplifying code (beginner)

Tags: jquery, simplify, hoverintent

I'm getting to grips with jQuery but find myself repeating code over and over again...

Surely there's a simpler way to write this:

```
$('#more-mcr, #more-hilton, #more-lpool').hide();


$('#mcr-hatters').hoverIntent(function() {
    $('#mcr-hilton').stop().animate({opacity: 0.4});
    $('#more-mcr').fadeIn({duration:200});
}, function() {
    $('#mcr-hilton').stop().animate({opacity: 1});
    $('#more-mcr').fadeOut({duration:200});
});

$('#mcr-hilton').hoverIntent(function() {
    $('#mcr-hatters').stop().animate({opacity: 0.4});
    $('#more-hilton').fadeIn({duration:200});
}, function() {
    $('#mcr-hatters').stop().animate({opacity: 1});
    $('#more-hilton').fadeOut({duration:200});
});

$('#lpool-hostel').hoverIntent(function() {
    $('#more-lpool').fadeIn({duration:200});
}, function() {
    $('#more-lpool').fadeOut({duration:200});
});

$('#offers-mcr').hoverIntent(function() {
    $('#offers-lpool').stop().animate({opacity: 0.4});
    $('#offers-bham').stop().animate({opacity: 0.4});
}, function() {
    $('#offers-lpool').stop().animate({opacity: 1});
    $('#offers-bham').stop().animate({opacity: 1});
});

$('#offers-lpool').hoverIntent(function() {
    $('#offers-mcr').stop().animate({opacity: 0.4});
    $('#offers-bham').stop().animate({opacity: 0.4});
}, function() {
    $('#offers-mcr').stop().animate({opacity: 1});
    $('#offers-bham').stop().animate({opacity: 1});
});

$('#offers-bham').hoverIntent(function() {
    $('#offers-lpool').stop().animate({opacity: 0.4});
    $('#offers-mcr').stop().animate({opacity: 0.4});
}, function() {
    $('#offers-lpool').stop().animate({opacity: 1});
    $('#offers-mcr').stop().animate({opacity: 1});
});
```

I'd also like to set the delay for hoverIntent but I don't think this is possible with the way I've written the code currently...?

Answer (score 2):

Add a class to the various items that you want to hover on, for example `hoverItem`.  Then you can use `$('.hoverItem').hoverIntent(function() ...);` to set multiple items at once.  Given the fat that the example you gave has two different opacities defined, I would create two classes.

Comment: Two classes may work if there are a lot of the same item, but if it's going to stay at this few, an ID selector may be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a named function (e. g. function myHover() {}) and then in your `.hoverIntent` reference it as `.hoverIntent(myHover)`.  Also, consider using the [Multiple Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) when you want two IDs to have the same attached function.